# global d3 modules with angular2 cli shows compile error

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular2-cli

I tried importing d3 in my files and of course this worked, but I also wanted to use d3-tip and this turned out to be difficult to import in the normal way so I looked at the angular2-cli docs and tried importing the files globally in the angular-cli.json

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/d3/build/*.js",
    "../node_modules/d3-tip"
  ],
```

this seems to work, and it actually renders correctly, but I get a whole bunch of errors in the console output

```
[default] D:\ang\stockdisplayapp\src\app\chart.component.ts:54:29
    Identifier 'd3' must be imported from a module
[default] D:\ang\stockdisplayapp\src\app\chart.component.ts:82:22
    Identifier 'd3' must be imported from a module
[default] D:\ang\stockdisplayapp\src\app\chart.component.ts:92:9
    Identifier 'd3' must be imported from a module
[default] D:\ang\stockdisplayapp\src\app\chart.component.ts:94:23
    Identifier 'd3' must be imported from a module
[default] D:\ang\stockdisplayapp\src\app\chart.component.ts:96:21
    Identifier 'd3' must be imported from a module
[default] D:\ang\stockdisplayapp\src\app\chart.component.ts:98:23
```

etc.

Any idea how to resolve these error messages?

Comment: Have you imported the d3 module into your ChartComponent?

Comment: thank you, if i also tried importing into the chart.component as well as importing globally it threw a different error. In the end i abandoned this approach and imported both d3 and d3-tip into the chart.component.  Having imported d3-tip into the chart component as d3Tip, it is then called  `const tip = d3Tip()`